# facebook-java-sdk unable to create "Ad", says using instagram a/c as placement when not really using anything

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to create Ad using facebook-java-sdk

```
val adCreative = new AdAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, context).createAdCreative()
  .setName(s"Test Creative +$TEST")
  .setObjectStorySpec(
    new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec()
      .setFieldLinkData(
        new AdCreativeLinkData()
          .setFieldCaption("http://www.field-caption.com")
          .setFieldImageHash(attachment1.getFieldImageHash)
            .setFieldLink("http://www.google.co.in")
              .setFieldMessage("try it out")
              )
      .setFieldPageId(FACEBOOK_PAGE)
  )
  .execute()

val ad = new AdAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, context).createAd()
  .setName(s"Test Ad +$TEST")
  .setAdsetId(adSet.getId)
      .setCreative(adCreative.getId)
  .setCreative(new AdCreative().setFieldId(adCreative.getId()))
  .setStatus(Ad.EnumStatus.VALUE_PAUSED)
  .execute()
```

However the createAd calls fails and results into exception with

```
com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1772103,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Instagram Account Is Missing","error_user_msg":"You're using Instagram as a placement. Please select an Instagram account to represent your business in your Instagram ads, or select a Facebook Page to use instead.","fbtrace_id":"FtpWRXVY1tH"}}
```

This was working fine couple of days back, but all of sudden has started throwing an exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify publisher platform to publish only on facebook

```
 val adSet = new AdAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, context).createAdSet()
  .setName(s"Test AdSet +$TEST")
  .setLifetimeBudget(20000L)
  .setStartTime(currentDateTime.toString())
    .setEndTime(currentDateTime.plusDays(1).toString())
      .setCampaignId(campaign.getId())
        .setIsAutobid(true)
        .setBillingEvent(AdSet.EnumBillingEvent.VALUE_IMPRESSIONS)
        .setOptimizationGoal(AdSet.EnumOptimizationGoal.VALUE_POST_ENGAGEMENT)
        .setTargeting(
              new Targeting()
                  .setFieldCustomAudiences(List(idNameCusAudience).asJava)
                    .setFieldPublisherPlatforms(List("facebook").asJava)
        )
        .setStatus(AdSet.EnumStatus.VALUE_PAUSED)
        .execute()
```

Comment: It really helped, and true that it is not mentioned in the marketing api prominently.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution, if you want your ad to show on instagram too you should be able to set a facebook page if there is no instagram account connected to the page, that is the default functionality in the ads manager.

Comment: I get this error everytime I try to create an Ad based on a post. How can I specify a page when creating/updating an Ad? @RickS

Comment: @K.D. Check out my answer, i would link to my support ticket with Facebook but they banned my other account and its gone. That should solve it for you

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to this answer since i just fought with this issue.
Our long running app that managed boosting just stopped working this month and was throwing the error the OP mentioned.
It appears that the default settings on Facebook's side changed. The [docs state](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs#newplacement) that the defaults are `facebook, audience_network, messenger`

Looking in the Ads Manager, it shows that the placement for the failed boost attempt now includes instagram as a placement. There doesn't seem to be any mention of this change anywhere that I could find.

So I did have to change the call to explicitly define `facebook, audience_network, messenger` as my [publisher_platform setting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs#placement) and not rely on the defaults.

Comment: Looks like they just recently updated the documentation to include it.

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers really answer what you need to do if you want to include Instagram.

In order to post to instagram you need an instagram account ID.

Every single page on Facebook has (or can have) an instagram 'account' without the user creating one.

What you need to do is (in this order):

1. Check if they have an instagram linked (if they do you use this ID)
2. Check for `page_backed_instagram_accounts` to see if their page has an instagram account that Facebook made for them to be able to advertise (this account is hidden and cannot be found on instagram) if they have this, use the ID from this account.
3. If for some reason their page has no instagram nor does it have `page_backed_instagram_accounts` then you will need to create a `page_backed_instagram_account`

The endpoints you are looking for are:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/[pageId]?fields=instagram_accounts
2. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/[pageId]?fields=page_backed_instagram_accounts

Comment: this was helpful. But how do you use the generated instagram account ID in fb api. I pass it as instagram_actor_id without success

Comment: @AlexandruR havent worked with the Facebook API in a while but from the code i wrote from when this was posted it looks like i do a `POST` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/[FB_API_VERSION]/[PAGE_ID]/page_backed_instagram_accounts` hope that helps